# Add an additional column to a panda dataframe comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a dataframe (df) containing two columns:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Banana |
| Chicken | Chicken |
| Dragonfruit | Egg |
| Fish | Fish |

What I want to do is create a third column that says whether the results in each column are the same. For instance:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Same |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Banana | No |
| Chicken | Chicken | Yes |
| Dragonfruit | Egg | No |
| Fish | Fish | Yes |

I've tried:
`df['Same'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Column A'] in row['Column B'],axis=1)`

Which didn't work.
I also tried to create a `for` loop but couldn't even get close to it working.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: The apply function should work:
`df['Same'] = df.apply(lambda row: "Yes" if row['Column 1'] == row['Column 2'] else "No", axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [**`np.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
import numpy as np

df['Same'] = np.where(df['Column 1'] == df['Column 2'], 'Yes', 'No')
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas the [`==` operator between `Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) returns a new `Series`

So you can use:

```py
df['Same'] = df['Column A'] == df['Column B']
df['Same'] = df['Same'].replace(True, 'Yes').replace(False, 'No')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using vectorisation**: You can make use of vectorisation to efficiently achieve the desired result. For example, you can use NumPy's `where` function:

```
df['Same'] = np.where(df['Column 1'] == df['Column 2'], 'Yes', 'No')
```

**Using apply**: If you do wish to use Pandas `apply()` function (e.g. as the data set is small and you wish to add additional logic) then the example below shows you how to do this to achieve the desired result.

```
df['Same'] = df.apply(lambda row: "Yes" if row['Column 1'] == row['Column 2'] 
                                        else "No", axis=1)
```

The above approach will place the value `'Yes'` in the `'Same'` column of the data frame if the values in `'Column 1'` and `'Column 2'` match, otherwise it will place the value `'No'`.

**Result**: The result of running either of the above code examples will be as follows:

```
      Column 1 Column 2 Same
0        Apple   Banana   No
1      Chicken  Chicken  Yes
2  Dragonfruit      Egg   No
3         Fish     Fish  Yes
```

**More information**: You can learn more about the limitations of `apply()` vs approaches that utilise vectorisation by [clicking here](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficient-pandas-apply-vs-vectorized-operations-91ca17669e84).

Comment: Don't use`apply` for such a simple comparison. This is a waste of pandas vectorial capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin`:

```
df_eq['Column1'].isin(df_eq['Column2']).replace({True:'Yes', False:'No'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.apply(lambda)` expression

```
df['Same'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x['Column 1']==x['Column 2'] else 'No', axis=1)
```

Comment: Don't use`apply` for such a simple comparison. This is a waste of pandas vectorial capabilities.